# Getting Windows Phone version and device name in Windows Phone 8.1 XAML

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

In Windows Phone 8 Silverlight I use

```
 Environment.OSVersion.ToString()
```

to get Windows Phone version and

```
DeviceStatus.DeviceManufacturer+" "+DeviceStatus.DeviceName
```

to get device name.

These APIs no longer work with Windows Phone 8.1 XAML. I have found

```
Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation()
```

this seems to return the manufacturer and device name but OS is returned as just "Windows Phone".

Is there a way to get the exact Windows phone version?

Comment: From what I've read, getting the version does not seem to be possible. May I ask why do you need it?

Comment: The documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion(v=vs.110).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.devicemanufacturer(v=vs.105).aspx says that it is supported in Windows Phone 8.1 XAML.

Comment: @yasen for an API call, they use it for some analytics

Comment: @cvraman works with 8.1 Silverlight but not 8.1 XAML

Comment: Did you ask the people with the API about this? They might have some idea. Also, for now you could just pass 8.1. Yeah, that's not a real solution, but I don't know if such exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is currently not possible In Windows Runtime 8.1 (Phone and Windows). It does look like it might be planned thanks to [Morten Nielsen and Pete Brown](https://twitter.com/Pete_Brown/status/457251346451030017)

**EDIT**: This is now possible in Windows 10. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31895625) as well as [this article](https://www.suchan.cz/2015/08/uwp-quick-tip-getting-device-os-and-app-info/) for more useful features.

Comment: and what about http://stackoverflow.com/a/24929167/429521 ? shouldn't I use that?

Comment: Firmware version is not OS version. There are many different version for a particular OS. While The main OS is 8.1, the actual version used depends on what updates MS or the carrier has pushed out.

Answer (score 2):

For 8.1, you can use this project on Github https://github.com/Microsoft/phone-info that includes an example application for retrieving both static and dynamic properties of a Windows Phone device.

For Windows 10, the APIs that were used to gather these data on (8 and 8.1) have changed. I have found one blog post https://www.suchan.cz/2015/08/uwp-quick-tip-getting-device-os-and-app-info/ for someone who has created a helper class that retrieves the following properties from a Windows 10 UWP app

`current OS family - phone/desktop/...`

`current OS build number - 10.0.10240.16413`

`current OS architecture - x86/x64/ARM`

`current App Display Name`

`current App Version - 3.0.2.0`

`current Device manufacturer - Nokia`

`current Device model - Lumia 1520`

In his post he shows how to get basic data about current device, operating system and application.

give it a try maybe it helps

Comment: Thanks, but my question is about 8.1 so this is not a solution for me.

Comment: for 8.1 you can use the DeviceStatus Properties under the DeviceStatus class in the Microsoft.Phone.Info Namespace

Comment: @IgorKulman I edited the answer to include 8.1 let me know if that does the job.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Phone 8.1:

```
Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation().FriendlyName
```

It worked for me!

Comment: That only returns the name of the device, not the OS version as asked for.

Comment: You also have the following properties:Id, OperatingSystem, SystemSku, SystemProductName, SystemManufacturer, SystemHardwareVersion, SystemFirmwareVersion, SystemFirmwareVersion

Comment: Oh. you're right it hasn't the versión numbre. Sorry

Comment: None these say Windows 8.1 or the extended version number, nor the devicename