# Environment.OSVersion does not exist

Tags: .net, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am creating a universal Windows App (Phone and metro) and I need to access the friendly name of the Operating System (such as Windows Phone 8.1). All the sources on the internet point to `Environment.OSVersion` but `Environment` does not contain a definition for `OSVersion`. Am I missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122013/getting-windows-phone-version-and-device-name-in-windows-phone-8-1-xaml

Answer (score 2):

I use this to get some stats:

```
Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation deviceInfo = new Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation();

string FriendlyName = deviceInfo.FriendlyName;
string OperatingSystem = deviceInfo.OperatingSystem;
string SystemManufacturer = deviceInfo.SystemManufacturer;
string SystemProductName = deviceInfo.SystemProductName;
```

Unfortunately, the *WindowsPhone* is not the full OS version like in Silverlight, it can only be *Windows* or *WindowsPhone*

Comment: interesting to see Microsoft removing such functionality from the SDK and not replacing it with something elegant. this "workaround" seems like a really ugly hack, but thanks anyway :)