# Get OS version through IoTHub Device Twin / Direct Method

Tags: azure-iot-hub

How can we get the Windows version installed on the device through IotHub Device Twin or Direct Method or Any other means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IoTHub SDKs can not get the version of the windows system installed on the device,they have no related API.[AnalyticsVersionInfo Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.profile.analyticsversioninfo) provides version information about the device family. Please see this topic of [Windows 10 get DeviceFamilyVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31783604/windows-10-get-devicefamilyversion).

Comment: Thanks for confirming